"他に" how to take it here?
かくして、否応なしの消灯により、眠る他に気を紛らす手段を失ってしまった
As far I can understand the sentence, the character says that due to the compulsory loss of light, there was no other method to distract themselves but sleep. Some lines later add they are indeed trying to sleep.
I understand 気を紛らす手段を失ってしまった is "Any method to distract themselves has disappear"
What kind of nuance here does 他に provide?
